# How can I delete duplicate video from a Youtube Playlist by its playlist ID?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

```
private static void RemoveVideo(YouTubeService youTubeService, string playlistId, string videoId)
{
    // Find the matching video item
    var videos = youTubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
    videos.PlaylistId = playlistId;

    var video = videos.Execute().Items.Where(a => a.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId == videoId).SingleOrDefault();

    if (video == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Video not found!", nameof(videoId));
    }

    // Now delete it by it's inner ID
    var playlistInsertRequest = youTubeService.PlaylistItems.Delete(video.Id);
    playlistInsertRequest.Execute();
}
```

1. I can delete a video to this playlist with the code above. But I can't delete the video if position of video >5 in this playlist. How can I delete it?
2. I can't delete duplicate video in this playlist. How can delete duplicate video in this playlist?

Comment: define cant delete do you have an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about the YouTube API, but after a quick read of the holy documentation:

1- PlaylistItems will, by default, return only 5 items. You should increment the value of the MaxResults property.

```
videos.PlaylistId = playlistId;
videos.MaxResults = 50;
```

2- You should iterate through videos items, otherwise you'll miss the duplicated videos.

```
foreach (var video in videos.Execute().Items.Where(a => a.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId == videoId))
{
// do your magic
}
```

Don't forget to have a deeper read of their awesome documentation:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#.net

Comment: I am truly grateful for your support. My code was running great. I'll read more in-depth about the YouTube API docs. Thank you very much! Wish you happy weekend!

Comment: Glad to be helpful, happy coding!